# display numbers on pie chart

Tags: java, android, charts

I've developed an android application to display a pie chart. I have used the `achartengine` library to do this. 
With this code below I get the pie chart output with 3 portions labeled as mentioned in categorySeries. I want to display the percentage values on the pie diagram. How can i do this?

```
public static final GraphicalView getPieChartView(Context context,
             CategorySeries dataset, DefaultRenderer renderer) {
         checkParameters(dataset, renderer);
         PieChart chart = new PieChart(dataset, renderer);

         return new GraphicalView(context, chart);
     }

     private static void checkParameters(CategorySeries dataset,
             DefaultRenderer renderer) {
         if (dataset == null
             || renderer == null
             || dataset.getItemCount() != renderer
                .getSeriesRendererCount()) {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                     "Dataset and renderer should be not null and the dataset number of items should be equal to the number of series renderers");
         }
     }
```

and this is my onCreate method

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
 int highc = bundle.getInt("high");
 int lowc = bundle.getInt("low");
 int medc = bundle.getInt("medium");



RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativestatsLayout);
TextView message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statText);
message.setText("\n\n\tTickets Summary");
message.setGravity(50);
//layout.addView(message);
//setContentView(message);


int[] colors = new int[] { Color.rgb(255, 0, 0),Color.rgb(220, 51,51), Color.rgb(255, 191, 0) };
DefaultRenderer renderer = buildCategoryRenderer(colors);

CategorySeries categorySeries = new CategorySeries("Tickets Chart");
categorySeries.getTitle();
categorySeries.add("critical", highc);
categorySeries.add("major ", medc);
categorySeries.add("minor ", lowc);



layout.addView(getPieChartView(this, categorySeries, renderer));
}

protected DefaultRenderer buildCategoryRenderer(int[] colors) {
    DefaultRenderer renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
    for (int color : colors) {
       SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
       r.setColor(color);

       renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }
    return renderer;
}
```

Comment: i get the pie chart output with 3 portions labled as mentioned in categorySeries, i want to display the percentages on the pie chart..

Comment: can anybody atleast suggest by which charting api of android could this be possible.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible using achartengine. I have faced the same problem and found the answer now. 
Use the 1.1.0-rc2 version of achart engine. You can download it here: http://www.achartengine.org/download/

This tutorial (http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-drawing-pie-chart-using-achartengine/) helps you to create pie chart using achartengine.

Add this line to your code to display the %of distribution in the Pie chart

```
defaultRenderer.setDisplayValues(true);
```

Reference: [How to set different values for Legend and Labels in piechart While I am using Chart Engine in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657432/how-to-set-different-values-for-legend-and-labels-in-piechart-while-i-am-using-c/15471237#15471237)

Comment: Percentage symbol (%) doesn't appear after the values. How to make that appear.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if you still have this issue. But if your pie chart is fairly simple, you should consider drawing it your self rather using a library for it.
This might help a bit.

https://github.com/blessenm/PieChartDemo